# how to insert followers list from twitter into database using PHP

Tags: php, database, twitter, phpmyadmin

I'm still new at this field of API & PHP so any help would be great!

I'm using the Twitter's API "followers/ids" and I would like to insert it into my table in "phpMyAdmin".

After I get the list, I want to insert it into the table that contains two columns - one is for the ID I entered and the other column is for the follower's ID.

I managed to get the list from the Twitter's API but unable to insert it into the table..

thanks for your help!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

using this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/list will help you find out what you want to do with the followers.

The SQL statement should be pretty easy with PHP. Create a DB connection and use the INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (parameter1, paramter2...).

Information on PHP + mySQL can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

So what I would do is to save the data from twitter in a class in PHP, and then save each in an array in PHP, when this is done I would use the SQL statement:

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (parameter_for_column1, parameter_for_column2... parameter_for_columnN);

the values can be variables from your PHP class then. This should be a valid query, else take a look here: www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

```
class dataFromTwitter
{
    public $id;
    public $screen_name;

    public function __construct($setID, $setScreenName)
    {
        $this->id = $setID;
        $this->screen_name = $setScreenName;
    }
}

function insertDB($twitterArray)
{
    foreach($twitterArray as $item)
    {
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('.$item->id.', '.$item->screen_name.'");
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I'm having trouble with the SQL statement.

How should i write it if I'm using
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids
thanks

Comment: So do you have a Connection to your database? and which type of datebase are you using MySQL, PgSQL or some other implementation og SQL?

Comment: yes, I have a connection. I also managed to retrieve the followers ids but I don't know how to write the SQL statement in order to insert the data into the table. I'm using MySQL.. again, thanks

Comment: Edited the original post - please check it out to see if it helps you.

Comment: hi ArchiFloyd, what do you mean "save the data from twitter in a class in PHP"? which class and how can I do that?
I got all the data in one variable called "$connection" (like on my comment to Jurijs), how should I write the SQL statement for your opinion?
thanks

Comment: unfortunately this is still unclear to me (new at this world). I don't understand who to connect the "class" to the data i get from twitter.
thanks for your patience

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I'm still stuck.. the Object Oriented is not my strongest side. this is where I'm stuck:
// Get firends account info
$connection->request('GET', $connection->url('1.1/followers/ids'), array('screen_name' => 'XXX'));

// Get the HTTP response code for the API request
$response_code = $connection->response['code'];

// Convert the JSON response into an array
$response_data = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);

print_r($response_data);

Comment: $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root');
if (!$conn)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else 
  echo 'Connected successfully';
 print "<br />";
 $db_selected = mysql_select_db('db',$conn);
 if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can't use db : " . mysql_error());
  }

now, after I retrieve the data from Twitter and connected to my DB (in phpMyAdmin) I'm stuck... thank again!!

Comment: $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','light_db'); dunno if it help you, but have you tried using this ? (with the I in myslqi)

Comment: thanks for your help:
here is the answer how I did it:
foreach ($response_data['ids'] as $value)
   {
   print_r($value);
   print "<br />";
   $query = "INSERT into tbl_edges (Source, Target,Directed,Date) VALUES (".$value.",".$Current_id.",'Directed',".$Current_Time.")";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Invalid INSERT " . mysql_error());
   
   }
   print_r("End of Step 4");
   print "<br />";

Answer (score 0):

You just get the followers id and put the variable into the `insert into` sql statement, also you can start from here: `https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids`

Comment: hi, I managed to get the followers id like this:
$connection->request('GET', $connection->url('1.1/followers/ids'), array(  'screen_name' => 'xxx'));
how can I insert it now to my table that it's called "light_db"

thanks